# How to count using Interrupts

Tags: c, interrupts, stm8

I have an issue where I want to count how many times I hit a switch using an interrupt. I tried placing the count variable inside the main but it claims that count does not exist. I put count inside the pragma but I know that will reset the count value to 0. How should I approach this problem?

I'm using the STM8S003K3

```
volatile int count = 0;

#pragma vector = 8
__interrupt void EXTI_PORTD_IRQHandler(void){   
   count++;
   PD_ODR_ODR3 = !PD_ODR_ODR3;
}

void main() {
   __disable_interrupt();
   PD_ODR = 0;             //  All pins are turned off.
   PD_DDR = 0xff;          //  All pins except PD4 are outputs.
   PD_CR1 = 0xff;          //  Push-Pull outputs.
   PD_CR2 = 0xff;          //  Output speeds up to 10 MHz.
   //
   //  Now configure the input pin.
   //
   PD_DDR_DDR4 = 0;        //  PD4 is input.
   PD_CR1_C14 = 0;         //  PD4 is floating input.
   //
   //  Set up the interrupt.
   //
   EXTI_CR1_PDIS = 2;      //  Interrupt on falling edge only.
   EXTI_CR2_TLIS = 0;      //  Falling edge only.
   __enable_interrupt();

   while (1) {
       __wait_for_interrupt();
   }
}
```

Comment: Declare "volatile int count = 0;" outside of your main and interrupt routine to make it file scope

Comment: By the way, make sure you debounce your button/switch, or the results may be unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

Make it a volatile global variable; declare and initialize it outside all functions. Then you increment within your ISR and print the modified value in main(). Something like:

```
static volatile int count = 0;

isr(){
  count++;
...
}

void main(){
  debug_print(count);
...
}
```

The volatile keyword is to prevent your compiler from optimizing away the variable, since its not seen to change in the normal program flow.

EDIT:
Declaring the variable static, like Lundin suggested, restricts its scope to this particular file, so that the variable is not visible outside this source file. You should use this only if the ISR and main() are defined within the same file.

Comment: I was taught that global variable is bad programming. or am I wrong?

Comment: Its usually recommended to reduce usage of global variables to prevent potential name collisions and unintended modifications. In this case though, since ISRs dont take arguments, its about the only way you can pass data between your main program and the ISR.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly but I have another issue related to it. I want to count but every time I want to stop the debug to see how many times I press the button I got this error. Failed to stop target: gdi-error. Abort command is not possible in current CPU state. It only works if I have a breakpoint but that is not an ideal.

Comment: @G.Han update the code in your post. Include everything.

Comment: What do you mean? I assume I am getting that error because I am in an infinity while loop, may be.

Comment: @G.Han i meant that i want to see your code.

Comment: It's the same code with volatile int count = 0; on top of the #pragma vector = 8

I updated the code above

Comment: @G.Han I dont see any means of viewing the current count. You can setup a UART connection btw your PC and the STM8 so that it prints the current count to the UART port each time count is changed. You can create a global flag 'char modified = 0;'. When you increment count in the ISR, you set the flag. In main(), you check if modified == 1; if it is, you print count and then clear the flag.

Comment: @G.Han I also dont see why you are calling a function named 'wait_for_interrupt()' explicitly. Interrupts, once enabled, will be triggered and when the associated event occurs. Or is this peculiar to the STM8?

Comment: @TisteAndii To go idle and avoid busy-waiting? - Agreed, it's not functionally necessary but good practice to save power. However, it may be that the CPU cannot be debugged while in idle mode, so the OP should try and remove the call for testing.

Comment: I commented out the 'wait_for_interrupt()' and was able stop my program and see my count value.

Comment: Global variables are indeed bad and there is never a reason to use them. Use _file scope_ variables instead. `static volatile uint32_t count;`.

Comment: @Lundin But STM32 StdPeriph places all interrupt handlers in separate file. So you may have need to cross the file scope with extern. Is there any alternative to global variables in this case?

Comment: @TisteAndii The _interrupt vector table_ should be in one file. Give it the relevant header file includes, then declare the actual ISRs where they belong. SPI interrupt inside SPI driver, timer interrupt inside timer driver etc. There is no reason why anything in your code but the SPI driver should talk with the SPI interrupt - otherwise your program design is flawed.

Comment: @Lundin Well, thats the general design in StdPeriph. You include "stm32fxxx_it.h" which is the header for the interrupt handlers and then you edit "stm32fxxx_it.c" and fill in the bodies of the interrupt handlers you need. And thats how they use it in their examples. Flawed design, like you say?

Comment: @TisteAndii Pre-made code you get from embedded systems compiler vendors is almost always crap. This goes for register maps and start-up code as well. You always get much better quality if you toss their crap out and re-write it yourself. But doing so takes time of course, so it might not be an option for every project.